# Adding a new Shapefile to GeoServer through REST API

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, php, geoserver-rest-api

I'm trying to interact with GeoServer's REST API using PHP's cURL and I'm having an issue when uploading a new Shapefile...

This is my `uploadShapefile` method:

```
public function uploadShapefile($zip, $ws, $ds) {

    if (!$ws || !$ds) {
        return false;
    }

    $fd = fopen($zip, 'rb');
    if (!$fd) {
        return false;
    }

    $headers = ['Content-Type: application/zip'];

    $settings = [
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD        => $this->passwordString,
        CURLOPT_PUT            => true,
        CURLOPT_UPLOAD         => true,
        CURLOPT_REFERER        => true,
        CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_INFILE         => $fd,
        CURLOPT_INFILESIZE     => filesize($zip),
    ];

    $endpoint = "rest/workspaces/$ws/datastores/$ds/file.shp";
    $response = $this->call($endpoint, $settings);

    fclose($fd);
    return $response;

}
```

My `call` method just uses cURL and returns the HTTP Response code

```
private function call($endpoint, $settings) {

    // $this->service is 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/'
    $ch = curl_init($this->service . $endpoint);

    foreach ($settings as $setting => $value) {
        curl_setopt($ch, $setting, $value);
    }

    // Execute
    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);

    // Result
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    return $info['http_code'];
}
```

When I call the `uploadShapefile` method it creates the *datastorage* in the specified *workspace*, **BUT** its *Shapefile Location* under *Connection Parameters* is empty and it also doesn't create the new layer for the feature type.

I've checked my `$fd` and it can read the zip file. Am I missing something?

---

**Edit:**

If I use CLI `curl` the behaviour is the same (datastorage created but no layer) and I get:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> PUT /geoserver/rest/workspaces/myworkspace/datastores/streets/file.shp HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: application/zip
> Content-Length: 215432
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
< Date: Mon, 14 Nov 2016 17:26:40 GMT
< Date: Mon, 14 Nov 2016 17:26:41 GMT
< Server: Noelios-Restlet-Engine/1.0..8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: does it work from the cli - curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/zip"
  --data-binary @roads.zip
  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/acme/datastores/roads/file.shp

Comment: also what is the response?

Comment: Response is `202`, @iant

Comment: @iant, I've edited adding CLI Curl verbose output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after many tries I discovered that this behaviour was **caused by the absence of a `.prj` file in my `zip`**.

So, the code is correct. It happens exactly the same in CLI's cURL.